# Cant dismiss my previous alertcontroller completely

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I am trying to use one single alert controller which include multiple alert showing functions and one dismiss function.But I am having [this warning](http://puu.sh/ipsxq/eb0e16ceb8.png) in my console and my other alert don't show.I wonder why?and the solution for that.

Here is my alert controller

```
import UIKit

class MyAlertViewController: UIViewController {

var myAlertController : UIAlertController!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func displayLoadingAlert(viewController: UIViewController?) -> UIAlertController {

    var controllerToPresent = viewController
    if controllerToPresent == nil {
        controllerToPresent = self
    }

    //create an alert controller
    myAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Loading...", message: “We are receiving data,please wait“, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

    controllerToPresent!.presentViewController(myAlertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    return myAlertController
}

func connectionErrorAlert(viewController: UIViewController?) -> UIAlertController {

    var controllerToPresent = viewController
    if controllerToPresent == nil {
        controllerToPresent = self
    }

    //create an alert controller
    myAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Not Connected", message: “No internet Connection”, preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default,handler:nil)
    myAlertController.addAction(defaultAction)

    controllerToPresent!.presentViewController(myAlertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    return myAlertController
}

func requestTimeOutErrorAlert(viewController: UIViewController?) -> UIAlertController {

    var controllerToPresent = viewController
    if controllerToPresent == nil {
        controllerToPresent = self
    }

    //create an alert controller
    myAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Request Time Out", message: “Please Click Retry”, preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default,handler:nil)
    myAlertController.addAction(defaultAction)

    controllerToPresent!.presentViewController(myAlertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    return myAlertController
}

func dismissLoadingAlert(){
    myAlertController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

}
```

I use to do `dismissLoadingAlert()` when I get the results from API.But,when I don't get the results from API.i used to do this delegate method from my protocol.

```
func didNotReceiveAPIResults(results: Bool,error:NSError){
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        // This condition will be enter if we dont get the results and show user with alert.
        if (results) {
            // I have done dismiss first data receiving alert,what do i doing wrong?
            self.myAlertController.dismissLoadingAlert()
            if error.localizedDescription == "The Internet connection appears to be offline."{
                self.myAlertController.connectionErrorAlert(self)
                self.carTableView.hidden=true
                self.retryButton?.hidden=false
                self.retryButton?.enabled=true
            }
            if error.localizedDescription == "Request Time Out."{
                self.myAlertController.requestTimeOutErrorAlert(self)
                self.carTableView.hidden=true
                self.retryButton?.hidden=false
                self.retryButton?.enabled=true
            }

        }else{
            self.myAlertController.displayLoadingAlert(self)
            self.retryButton?.hidden=true
            self.retryButton?.enabled=false
            self.carTableView.hidden=false
            self.carTableView.reloadData()
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are on the wrong track. You should not subclass this controller.

> The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

If you need a convenience class, refactor using a `NSObject` subclass that presents dynamic `UIAlertController` instances.

Comment: I am new to swift.I don't know what to do now.Is there any way that i can write my custom alert view to show and dismiss successfully.Thank you.I really need to call this custom alert from my view controllers class

Comment: Short answer - you should not. - Long answer, just subclass a normal `UIViewController` and present it modally. For the types of alerts you want to display, you might also want to look at 3rd party frameworks such as MBProgressHUD.

Comment: yeah,thanks for the help,i now subclass to UIViewController.But,i still cant solving the error which was "Attempt to present xxxxxx.... while a presentation is in progress"

Comment: Don't worry about the error. It is caused by you messing with private APIs which won't be the case once you cease subclassing UIAlerController.

Comment: No,I changed my subclass to UIViewController.But,the problem is after i dismiss first alert which was title with "Loading..." and display the second alert because of internet connection,the second alert doesn't display and show the above warning.Why i cant successfully dismiss my first alert

Comment: If you can't do it, you should stick with my "short answer" ;-).